# Unable to resolve 'react-navigation'

Tags: npm, react-native, react-navigation

Am trying out react-native and get below error, when I install and try to use react-navigation (import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';).

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL6jl.png)

I use the following command to install "react-navigation" : **npm install --save react-navigation**

On running above command I get **'react-navigation'** folder under **node_modules** folder, with just a single file (**package.json**). Below is the content of the file:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "react-navigation@0.0.0",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "react-navigation",
        "name": "react-navigation",
        "rawSpec": "0.0.0",
        "spec": "0.0.0",
        "type": "version"
      },
      "/Users/rakesh-1812/Documents/REACT_JS/SimpleApp"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "react-navigation@0.0.0",
  "_id": "react-navigation@0.0.0",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/react-navigation",
  "_nodeVersion": "4.2.1",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-12-west.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/react-navigation-0.0.0.tgz_1459892254509_0.1584461957681924"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "ericvicenti",
    "email": "ericvicenti@gmail.com"
  },
  "_npmVersion": "2.14.7",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "react-navigation@0.0.0",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": "react-navigation",
    "name": "react-navigation",
    "rawSpec": "0.0.0",
    "spec": "0.0.0",
    "type": "version"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER",
    "/"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-navigation/-/react-navigation-0.0.0.tgz",
  "_shasum": "1e0f865235cdb4d4aa8086484fd3690ff73df553",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "react-navigation@0.0.0",
  "_where": "/Users/rakesh-1812/Documents/REACT_JS/SimpleApp",
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": "Coming Soon",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "1e0f865235cdb4d4aa8086484fd3690ff73df553",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-navigation/-/react-navigation-0.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "ericvicenti",
      "email": "ericvicenti@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "name": "react-navigation",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "scripts": {},
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

Can someone please help me resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can i see your project's package.json

Comment: You need to restart your packager every time you add a new library, usually this is the most common issue with that error.

Comment: @Codesingh Below is my project's package.json {
  "name": "SimpleApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.42.3",
    "react-navigation": "0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: The react-navigation module has not installed properly. I would try deleting the node_modules folder, remove the "react-navigation": "0.0.0" from your package.json, and run npm install and npm install --save react-navigation again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

React navigation is still in beta. It works for me when I use the command:

```
npm install --save react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.7
```

This is the latest release. https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/releases

Answer (score 7):

You must stop your node server and start it again.

Do it:

```
sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:8081 | grep LISTEN
```

It will listen of the services that are running on port 8081. By default, react native server runs on it. Then, execute the command below to kill the server process.

```
kill -9 <cma process id>
```

Finally, run your project again with

```
react-native run-ios
```

on the project folder

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to install react-native, tried everything from the internet. Using Yarn instead of npm resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing react-navigation stack, `npm i react-navigation-stack`. Then `import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'`

Stop the server and run your project again.