# After installing 'react-navigation' The development server returned response code:500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am beginner in react-native and I am getting below error, when I install and try to use react-navigation 
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
I have tried a lot of link to resolve this but didn't find any solution. Below are the links:

[Unable to resolve 'react-navigation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054394/unable-to-resolve-react-navigation)

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1846

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968/

[image]

Please help me resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try resetting the packager cache?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Working for me**

```
npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/stack
```

**Import like this**

```
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

**OR**

Please make sure you are not getting any error in your terminal like this

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `**modules_name**` from `node_modules\
```

that can be the cause of that.

if you are getting please follow the command

```
 npm install modules_name
```

for every module

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see Path to react/lib/ReactComponentWithPureRn. It not find path.

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem now.

**How to fix**

When I look the `node modules` folder I can't see the react-navigation module.

Then I re-install the module with `# npm install --save react-navigation`

After restart the bundler with `npm start` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i face this problem and fixed it in this way:

> According to [document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started) 
>   we must install all dependencies like :

```
 react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated, react-native-screens and react-native-safe-area-context
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue.
What I found to fixed the issue for me was.

1. Run code in terminal

   npm i react-navigation-stack
2. Run the below code by opening terminal in your project directory

   npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view react-native-safe-area-context
3. Lastly running expo clearing the cache(Did this for good measure).

   expo start -c

   Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-stack